# Way to see validation request to user which typically happens when they try to log in from different I

Tags: security

Is there a way we can see when SF send a validation request to user which typically happens when they try to log in from different IP address

Comment: are you looking for validation or verfication?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **Identity Verification History**

It can be reached from Setup --> Manage Users --> Identity Verification History

**Identity Verification History**

> As an admin, use Identity Verification History to monitor and audit up to 20,000 records of your org users’ identity verification attempts from the past six months. For example, suppose that two-factor authentication is enabled when a user logs in. When the user successfully provides a time-based, one-time password as proof of identity, that information is recorded in Identity Verification History.

From more information [Refer this](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=security_verification_history.htm&siteLang=en_US)